# Issues with JAXB bindings

Tags: jaxb

I have a requirement for customizing the JAXB bindings for a SOAP client. I need to impose bindings at specific nodes available in the WSDL. The WSDL schema looks like:

```
<xs:complexContent mixed="false">

 <xs:extension base="q1:RequestBase" xmlns:q1="http://www.epsilon.com/webservices/">

  <xs:sequence>

      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="RegisterDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
```

```
 </xs:extension>

</xs:complexContent>
```

I need to apply binding for 'RegisterDate' attribute. I have added the following binding:

parseMethod="com.dunkindonuts.website.loyalty.util.DateAdapter.parseDateTime"

printMethod="com.dunkindonuts.website.loyalty.util.DateAdapter.printDateTime"/>

However, it is not working. When i apply this binding on global level, it works perfectly fine.

Can anyone provide any pointers to resolve this issue?

Regards,
Namit

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from your original post if your non-global binding included the schema location and/or binding node (xpath)??? something like:

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="PATH_TO_YOUR_SCHEMA">
    <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='RegisterDate']">
        <jxb:property>
            <jxb:baseType ...
```